# How can I implement this Array.sort method into my actionPerformed?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, sorting, actionlistener

I have this Array.sort method in one class to list my objects from highest to lowest:

```
public static void sortFilm(Film[] array) {
    Arrays.sort(array, new Comparator<Film>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Film f1, Film f2) {
            return Double.compare(f1.getFinalScore(), f2.getFinalScore());
        }
    });
    printArr(array);
}
```

I intend to use it inside an actionPerformed for my listener class but I don't know how to create the necessary parameter (Film[]) to make use of the Array.sort method. My intention is to show a list of all objects from highest to lowest once the specific button is pressed.

Thanks in advance!

edit:

This is how I think it will sort of look like:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    this.cm.sortFilm(?);
}
```

Question mark is the missing parameter.

Comment: I'm not sure how we can help here since how are we going to be able to guess how to create a Film array based on the scant code that you've posted. Consider creating a valid [mcve], posting the code here, and thereby helping us better understand your problem. Also, you may be better off using `ArrayList<Film>` here and not an array of Film.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, I'm new to all this. The other poster helped out plenty though. Still, thanks for the disposition!

Comment: Just note that you will learn much more if you at least try to solve your problem before posting here. And even if you don't succeed, you'll be able to ask a much better question, one that shows us your attempt and in this way shows us exactly what has you confused. Otherwise you're essentially asking someone to write code for you, and that's not good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you need to sort Film objects together you need a compareTo function to compare each 2 Films together, you can do that in `Film Class` by implementing `Comparable<Film>` then implementing the `compareTo` method in the class.

After That , Hold your films in any `collection` as `ArrayList` instead of array then simply call `Collections.sort(films)` to get your films list in increasing or decreasing order .

Here is the a Film class for demonstration:

```
public class Film implements Comparable<Film>{
  int finalScore ;

  public Film(int finalScore){
      this.finalScore = finalScore;
  }

  public int getFinalScore(){
      return this.finalScore;
  }

  @Override
  public int compareTo(Film film2) {
      return Double.compare(this.finalScore, film2.finalScore);
  }
}
```

And this is the main :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Film> films = new ArrayList<>();
        films.add(new Film(100));
        films.add(new Film(400));
        films.add(new Film(200));
        films.add(new Film(300));
        /*reverse order is the reversed order of your compareTo method
         , as you need Decreasing manner and the compareTo method
          outputs the Increasing manner then you need to reverse it,
          remove this comparator if you need it increasing.*/
        Collections.sort(films,Comparator.reverseOrder());
    for (Film film : films) {
        System.out.print(film.finalScore+" "); // prints 400 300 200 100
       }     
    }
```

So your actionPerformed will be like this

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Collections.sort(films,Comparator.reverseOrder());
    //now films are sorted! use films objects to do anything you need

}
```

Comment: Hey you again! This is getting embarrassing, it turned out I wasn't clear enough in my other post. I guess I can figure it out now and can implement it in my code. Thanks a lot! Again!

Comment: No Problem at all :) 
I'm happy to help you at anytime:)